# How to assign multiple arrays in one single array in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, multidimensional-array, nested-lists

I have 3 different arrays that I want to join in one array in a specified format
Example:

```py
arr_1 = [A,B,C]
arr_2 = [1,2,3]
arr_3 = [E,F,G]
```

I want the result array to look like this:

```py
arr_result = [[A,1,E],[B,2,F],[C,3,G]]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways you can achieve this
of of them is to use zip function
here is an example

```
arr_1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
arr_2 = [1, 2, 3]
arr_3 = ['E', 'F', 'G']

arr_result = []

for a, b, c in zip(arr_1, arr_2, arr_3):
    arr_result.append([a, b, c])

print(arr_result)
```

in this example, the code will iterate over the elements of each array and create a new array with the elements from each array.
This code assumes that arrays are same length.

another way is using list comprehension

```
arr_1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
arr_2 = [1, 2, 3]
arr_3 = ['E', 'F', 'G']

arr_result = [[a, b, c] for a, b, c in zip(arr_1, arr_2, arr_3)]

print(arr_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This list generator should do the trick:

```py
arr_1 = ['A','B','C']
arr_2 = [1,2,3]
arr_3 = ['E','F','G']

arrays = [arr_1,arr_2,arr_3]
print([[arr[i] for arr in arrays] for i in range(3)])
>> [['A', 1, 'E'], ['B', 2, 'F'], ['C', 3, 'G']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
arr1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
arr2 = [1, 2, 3]
arr3 = ["E", "F", "G"]
arr4 = [[ *i ] for i in zip(arr1, arr2, arr3)]
```

Output:

```py
[['A', 1, 'E'], ['B', 2, 'F'], ['C', 3, 'G']]
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use also for loop :

```
l=[]
for i in range(len(arr_1)):
        l.append([arr_1[i],arr_2[i],arr_3[i]])
```